# How to remove google apps from /data/data directory?

Tags: applications, root-access, google

Rooted (w/ SuperSU + TWRP Recovery) Nexus 7 (2012 Wifi, Grouper)

I am unable to remove apps from the `/data/data` folder on my tablet. When I remove them then reboot the system, they reappear. How do I permanently remove them? I tried deleted them from `packages.list` as well.

Thanks

Comment: `/data/data/` only holds user data, apps are in `/data/app` and `/system/app`

Comment: That is not the case for me. `/data/app` holds the apps I've installed and I have no `/system/app` directory. Only `/system/bin` which is empty. 

I want to remove the `com.google.*` apps from `/data/data`, but like I said in the OP, they reappear upon reboot. What drives their regeneration?

Comment: Well, there are 3 directories where apps reside: `/data/app`, `/system/app` and `/system/priv-app`. You only delete their *userdata* but never the actual *app files* themselves. Google apps are usually bundled with the system and cannot be uninstalled without root.

Comment: Please note in the OP "Rooted Nexus 7..." I have root. How can I uninstall these `com.google.*` apps?

Comment: I know answers are not supposed to go in comments, but since I don't really know whether it works with system apps, you can use the package manager to uninstall apps like the official Android docs say (https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#pm). Otherwise: Just delete the APK files. You may need to search for it, but they are in one of the directories I pointed out, search in the directories as well. The package manager should also give you a way to display the location of APK file, IIRC

Comment: No go. 

1. `user5@system:~$ adb shell`
2. `shell@grouper:/ $ su`
3. `root@grouper:/ # pm uninstall com.google.android.apps.docs`  
4. `Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]`  
`1|root@grouper:/ # `

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Thanks to @GiantTree for guiding me a bit. Here are the steps I performed to remove google apps from my Nexus 7.

1. Enter TWRP Recovery
2. Click Mount
3. Check System
4. Then either navigate to `/system/app/` and delete apps OR
5. Open terminal on laptop, `adb shell & cd /system/app` then `rm -rf com.google.android.xyz`

The key for me was MOUNTING THE SYSTEM PARTITION. Without that step, I was getting a failure.